# How to properly use git submodule to clone entire spring app as a core for multiple projects?

Tags: java, spring, git, maven

Heres my problem, right now my company has a "coreApp" that is basically a spring server application with some basic features that we reuse in all projects.
To use this core app when we make a new project we import the core app repo in gitlab and then in git we add a git remote to our project that points to the core app repo.
Then we work normally on our origin master and when we want to pull changes (once in a while we update the core app) from the core app we change branch to remote/coreapp/master and we merge from there to origin/master. Naturally we face a ton of merge conflicts that are a pain in the ass.
Im wondering is there a way to use the "git submodule" feature to import the whole coreapp as a submodule and then work on the project in such a way that we dont touch the core app java/src folder or any other folder and then have the whole new app build and run smoothly with 2 java/src folders, resources etc.
This way we could then just update the submodule when the coreapp gets a facelift without having to solve a ton of merge conflicts. Also the maven needs to do its thing propperly.

Comment: @torek ive noticed you have a lot of git experience so im tagging u here in hopes of some assistance, tnx in advance.

Comment: That kind of tagging doesn't work (not sure how/if you could do anything on SO that *would* work here). Luckily for you I saw your question when I was going through all the new Git questions.  If the `coreApp` repository fits in as a subdirectory of your main project, you definitely *can* make it a submodule. I personally hate submodules though: people call them "sob-modules" for good reasons. Consider just using it as a separate repository without even submodule-izing it. If that works, you can submodule-ize it later if you like.